# adding numbers in for loop javascript

Tags: javascript

I need to sum all my numbers from a for loop with javascript

```
var nums = ['100','300','400','60','40'];

for(var i=1; i < nums.length; i++){

        var num = nums[i] + nums[i];

        alert(num);
}​
```

can someone help http://jsfiddle.net/GYpd2/1/

the outcome i am looking for is 900

Comment: What you are currently doing is concatenating each string with itself and assigning the result to `num`. I recommend to read the [MDN JavaScript Guide](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/JavaScript/Guide) to learn the basics.

Answer (score 29, accepted):

```
var nums = ['100','300','400','60','40'];
var sum = 0;

for(var i=0; i < nums.length; i++){

    sum += parseInt(nums[i]);

}

alert(sum);
```

Tested: http://jsfiddle.net/GYpd2/6/ (thanks to user1503606)

If `nums` contains numbers only there is no need for `parseInt()`.

Answer (score 8):

Prime example for ES5's `Array.prototype.reduce` method. Like:

```
var nums  = ['100','300','400','60','40'];

var total = nums.reduce(function(a,b) {
    return (+a)+(+b);
});
```

Demo: http://jsfiddle.net/FwfmE/

Answer (score 5):

```
var nums = ['100','300','400','60','40'], 
    num = 0;

for (var i = 0; i < nums.length; i++) {
    num += +nums[i];
}
alert(num);
​
```

Comment: @SnowBlind, Are you kidding? :)

Comment: Sorry, my bad.. But what is the meaning of `+` on the left of `nums[i];` ?

Comment: This is unary operator, it uses to convert string to integer

Answer (score 4):

Do it like this

```
var nums = ['100','300','400','60','40'];
var total = 0;    

for(var i=0; i < nums.length; i++){
    total = total + Number(nums[i]);
}
alert(total);
```

1. The loop starts with 0 not 1.
2. `total` variable needs to be declared before the loop or else it will not preserve the previous addition.
3. Use Number() to convert string to number.
4. Adding string means concatitation `'100'` + `'200'` will give `'100200'`.

Answer (score 3):

```
var num, nums = [100,300,400,60,40];

for ( var i=1; i < nums.length; i++ ) {
    num += nums[i];
}​

alert(num);
```

Answer (score 2):

If you have a [reduce function](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/Reduce) , you can just do this:

```
var nums = ['100','300','400','60','40'],
    sum = nums.reduce(function(accum, val) {return accum + Number(val);}, 0);
alert(sum);
```

Answer (score 2):

```
var nums = ['100','300','400','60','40'];
var num = 0; 

for(var i=0; i < nums.length; i++){
    num = parseInt(num) + parseInt(nums[i]);
}
```

This is how I did it. It's very similar to other's code, but a different way of writing it. You do need to start your initial i value in your for loop with 0.

Comment: Great! This is the only solution that is working here.

Answer (score 1):

Javascript is treating your numbers as strings, and concatenating them together instead of adding them like you expect.

Use `parseInt` to convert them into integers before adding:

```
var nums = ['100','300','400','60', 40];
var num = 0;

for(var i=1; i < nums.length; i++){
       num += parseInt(nums[i], 10);
       alert(num);
}​
```

The [second parameter](http://ajaxian.com/archives/the-parseint-gotcha) tells `parseInt` to use base 10.

Comment: what about the keyword var in the for loop?

Comment: I have eradicated all the `var`

Answer (score 1):

Here is [JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/GYpd2/5/)

and code is:

```
var num=0, nums = ['100','300','400','60','40'];

for(var i=0; i < nums.length; i++){            
        num += parseInt(nums[i]);  
}
  alert(num);
```

Answer (score 1):

```
var i, sum = 0, nums = ['100','300','400','60','40'];

for (i = 0; i < nums.length; i++) {
    sum += +nums[i];
}

alet(sum);
```

You shouldn't use the `var` statement inside a loop. Also the `parseInt` function used in other answers will always convert the number to an integer so it wouldn't work with floating point numbers. Prefixing the numbers with `+` will convert them to a number.

If you develop for the browser, using the `reduce` function might cause problems with older browsers - unless you find a polyfill for it.

Answer (score 1):

Here's an example that uses an extension of the Number prototype, similar to LINQ's sum method:

```
Array.prototype.sum = function () {
  var result = 0;
  this.forEach(function (o) { result += Number(o); });
  return result;
};

var sum = ['100','300','400','60','40'].sum();
```

Answer (score 1):

You can do something like this..

```
var nums = ['100','300','400','60','40'];

nums.reduceRight(function(a,b){return Number(a)+Number(b);})
```

Answer (score 1):

```
var nums = ['100','300','400','60','40'];
let sum =0;
    for(let numbers of nums){
 sum+=parseInt(numbers);
     }
alert(sum);
```

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! Code-only answers are not particularly helpful. Please add some descriptions of how this code solves the problem.

Comment: For arrays, it’s much easier to use a for…of loop to sum all the variables in the array . All you have to do is , declare a variable and set its value to 0. Then use the a for … of loop to iterate through the array and return the sum.

Answer (score 0):

You can try this:

```
var arr = ['100','300','400','60','40'];
var total = 0; 
for(var i in arr){
  total += parseInt(arr[i]);
}

console.log(total);
```

Output will be: 900

Or if value is Float, then try this:

```
var arr = [100.00,300.50,400.75,60.00,40.00];
    var total = 0; 
    for(var i in arr){
      total += parseFloat(arr[i]);
    }
    
    console.log(total.toFixed(2));
```

Output will be: 901.25